# C++ taking a pointer and turning it into a callable function

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reverse-engineering, function-calls

I am currently reverse engineering a program to learn how it works and have just completed disassembling a function that the program calls. The starting address of the function is stored in a pointer, and it takes 4 arguments. My goal is to now cast the pointer as a callable function.

I have seen this done before a year or two ago, but no longer have access to the example code that was used. Essentially, I want to take a pointer that points to the start of a function and convert it into this:

```
void AddValueToMain(void* basePtr, unsigned int value, __int64 compareValue, __int64 ONE_BILLION);
```

How can I cast this pointer so that I can call the function as if it were written in C++?

Comment: this might be possible, but is compiler-dependent. You need some kind of alternative, such as a pointer to a functor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `reinterpret_cast` to a function pointer. Assuming that `m_ptr` holds the pointer to the function:

```
auto AddValueToMain = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(void*,unsigned int,__int64,__int64)>(m_ptr);
```

Now you can call `AddValueToMain` just like a normal function:

```
AddValueToMain(ptr, 42, 2, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks! In addition to that, if I just had the base address of the function (let's say it's 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF), could I also cast like `auto AddValueToMain = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(void*,unsigned int,__int64,__int64)>(0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF) `

Comment: Yep. The mapping between integers and pointers is implementation defined, but if your platform supports it then that's a way to get what you want.